# How to read a XML file which is converted from PDF file in php?

Tags: php

Am doing php code to read a xml file which is generated from a pdf file...
  But i couldn't able to get the Nodes, here is the code which i have used...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml"); 
echo $xml->getName();
echo $xml->children();
```

I dint get any value for $xml->children(), What am missing here...

Comment: How are you going to ask a question about an XML file being parsed, and not post the XML file that you are trying to parse? Maybe there are no children under the root node of the file? Post the xml file and we'd be able to help more.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you convert a PDF to XML?

Comment: Hello Mr.Colin i cant put the file here...

Comment: Mr Fab, the conversion as follows   PDF to docx and then docx to XML...